# Two divs with same bottom and one overflowed; can't get it to work

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I have two divs that are side by side with the same parent div. The height of the first div is greater than the height of the second div and I want the height of the parent to be the same as the height of the second div. I'd like both divs to have the same bottom edge (so that the first div will overflow above the parent div). How can this be achieved?

For more clarity, here's a picture:

[image: https://postimg.org/image/4ummagdmh/fb661c94/]

Each rectangle is a different div; how do I get this kind of setup?

Comment: You need to show some code or no one can help.

Comment: Easy doable with Flexbox, are you using Flexbox?
https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Comment: Welcome! Please add a [mcve]

Comment: hi, i added a img to try and depict what i mean, i am not using flexbox

Answer (score 0, accepted):

absolutely position the taller div so that it's layout won't affect the parent, and give it `bottom: 0;` to align it to the bottom of the parent div.

```css
* { box-sizing: border-box; }
body {
  padding: 5em 0 0;
} 
.parent {
  border: 1px solid black;
  position: relative;
}
.tall {
  position: absolute;
  border: 1px solid green;
  left: 0; bottom: 0; width: 50%;
  height: 5em;
}
.short {
  border: 1px solid purple;
  margin-left: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="tall">tall</div>
  <div class="short">short</div>
</div>
```

Comment: hi it doesnt seem to overflow the parent div, see image i posted in original post

Answer (score 0):

```
  .container{display:flex;align-items:flex-end;} 
   #div1{ flex-basis:100px; }    
   #div2{flex-basis:200px;}
   //Flex-basis is the  width of divs
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```css
#child_1{
  height:20px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  width:200px;
  float:left;
}
#child_2{
  height:30px;
  border: 1px solid red;
    width:200px;
  float:left;
}
#parent{
  height:20px;
  border: 5px solid green;
    width:404px;
}
```

```html
<div id="parent">
<div id="child_1">
child 1 div
</div>
<div id="child_2">
child2  div
</div>
</div>
```